# How to display Date in DD/MM/YYYY H:MM AM/PM format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a DATETIME Column in a table and I need to show the date in the 
following format "DD/MM/YYYY H:MM AM/PM"

```
CreatedBy
2013-07-30 12:44:06.000
2013-07-30 12:45:57.000
2013-08-05 16:51:26.000
2013-08-05 19:08:18.000
2013-08-05 19:11:46.000
2013-09-12 12:44:27.000
```

I need the date like this--> `"30/07/2013 12.44 PM"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in SQL:

```
print convert(nvarchar(10), getdate(), 103) + right(convert(nvarchar(30), getdate(), 0), 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Date datetime = '2013-07-30 12:44:06.000',
 @Time time = '12:44:06.000', 
 @VarcharDate varchar(100), 
 @VarcharTime varchar(100)

 set @VarcharDate= CONVERT(varchar,@Date,111) -- get the date in the format you want 
 set @VarcharTime = CONVERT(varchar,@Date) -- get the time in format you want 
print @VarcharDate + ' '+SUBSTRING(@VarcharTime,13,LEN(@VarcharTime))
```

This will give you the desire output.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME
SET @Date = '2013-07-30 12:44:06.000'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @Date, 103)  + ' ' +
substring(convert(varchar(30), @Date, 100), 13, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT convert(varchar(20), GetDate(), 0);
```

To extract only AM/PM

```
   substring(convert(varchar(30), GetDate(), 9), 25, 2);
```